# Rails basic authentication with cutomized JSON failure message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, basic-authentication

I have got a Rails 5.2 app in API mode. If a request is supplied with correct Basic Authentication credentials, expected JSON data `{ status: true, data: 'test_user_data' }` will be rendered.

users_controller.rb

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :basic_authenticate

  def get_user_info
    render json: { status: true, data: 'test_user_data' }
  end

  private

  def basic_authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == 'test_name' && password == 'test_password'
    end
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
end
```

However, if Basic Authentication fails, only a plain text `HTTP Basic: Access denied.` is rendered.

What I would like to do is to render error messages in JSON in case of authentication failure, something like `{ status: false, message: 'basic authentication failed'}`.

What is the proper way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` takes an optional `message` parameter (which is, unfortunately, the second in the parameter list, therefore the `"Application"` for the first parameter).

In Rails 5 just change your code to:

```
def basic_authenticate
  message = { status: false, message: 'basic authentication failed' }.to_json

  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic("Application", message) do |username, password|
    username == 'test_name' && password == 'test_password'
  end
end
```

The implementation has changed in Rails 6 and therefore in Rails 6 the most basic implementation would look like this:

```
def basic_authenticate
  message = { status: false, message: 'basic authentication failed' }.to_json

  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic(nil, message) do |username, password|
    username == 'test_name' && password == 'test_password'
  end
end
```

Comment: `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('', message)` works for me, otherwise I would get `tr method not found` error.

Comment: @HamkuuShaw You are totally right. That parameter defaults to `nil` in Ruby 6.0. But in Ruby 5.2 it defaults to a string – to `"Application"` to be specific. I updated my answer to address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use rescue from in your `application_controller.rb` like below

```js
rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access # self defined exception

def deny_access
  render json: { status: false, message: 'basic authentication failed'}
end
```